# Pass multiple arguments/parameters to powershell workflow

Tags: powershell, powershell-workflow

I have a powershell workflow script as below:

```
workflow mytest{
    param($param1,$param2,$param3)
    //code
}

mytest $param1,$param2,$param3
```

Issue here is all the three params were received as array in `$param1`.

Comment: Remove the commata in your command line. The delimiter for different parameters is a whitespace / space charachter.

Answer (score 1):

Type your params

```
Workflow Test-Runbook
{
  Param
  (
   [Parameter(Mandatory=<$True | $False>]
   [Type]$<ParameterName>,

   [Parameter(Mandatory=<$True | $False>]
   [Type]$<ParameterName>
  )
  <Commands>
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/system-center/sma/overview-powershell-workflows?view=sc-sma-2019

Answer (score 1):

All you're doing is passing an array to $param1.  Powershell parameters always work that way.  \\code is not a comment.

```
workflow mytest{
    param($param1,$param2,$param3)
    "param1 $param1  param2 $param2  param3 $param3"
}

mytest 1 2 3

param1 1  param2 2  param3 3
```